# How to refactor a function with different struct pointers as parameters?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, refactoring, void

Suppose I have this piece of code, with 2 structs and a big function that receives this 2 structs as parameters:

```
typedef struct
{
  int field_A;
  int field2_A;
} A;

typedef struct
{
  int field_B;
  int field2_B;
} B;

void function_need_refactor(A *a, B *b)
{
  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
  {
    do_something(a->field_A);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    do_something(b->field2_B);
  }
}
```

How can I replace the both for loops to a single function? I thought about using void pointer and an identifier for each struct, but couldn't come up with an answer. Is there a clean way to refactor this or is it impossible?

```
void refactored_function(void* my_struct, char type_identifier) 
{ 
  //code to identify the type
  for(i=0; i < SIZE; i++) 
  {
    do_something((cast)my_struct->????);
  }
}
```

Comment: The example seems a bit contrived, so I'm not sure I understand the motivation for doing this. In the top example, you can easily join the bodies into one loop and it seems much cleaner than switching on two different structs, assuming you only ever have 2.

Comment: Is it always a struct which contains only ints?

Answer (score 0):

There are two modifications that come to mind here. First of all, both loops rely on the same counter and the counter is independent of the items in the loop body... Thus, logically, you should at least be able to do this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int field_A;
  int field2_A;
} A;

typedef struct
{
  int field_B;
  int field2_B;
} B;

void function_need_refactor(A *a, B *b)
{
  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
  {
    do_something(a->field_A);
    do_something(b->field2_B);
  }
}
```

But you may also be able to refactor `do_something()` to operate on both:

```
typedef struct
{
  int field_A;
  int field2_A;
} A;

typedef struct
{
  int field_B;
  int field2_B;
} B;

void function_need_refactor(A *a, B *b)
{
  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
  {
    do_something(a->field_A, b->field2_B);
  }
}
```

That way, you're only using one loop total, and the function is handling both fields on each loop iteration.